# How to have a container in SingleChildScroll to take max height available?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my current work progress.

[Emulator Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XUjzh.png)

And here's my current code.

```
Scaffold(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
                body: Stack(
                  children: [
                    Image.asset('assets/images/semi-circle-clip.png'),
                    SingleChildScrollView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      child: SafeArea(
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Container(...),
                            Container(...),
                            Container(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                                top: 8.0,
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                crossAxisAlignment:
                                    CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: [
                                  Container(
                                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
                                    child: Text(
                                      'Apps',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'SF Pro',
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w700,
                                        fontSize: 24.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Column(
                                    children: [
                                      CategoryList(
                                        analytics: analytics,
                                        observer: observer,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            )
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            );
```

I want the 'Apps' section with the white background to cover the bottom area of the screen fully.

I have tried giving the container `height:double.infinity` and this gives me the `RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#829ba relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1785 pos 12: 'hasSize'` error.

I have tried covering the 'Apps' container with `Expanded` and that gives me the `RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.` error.

Please help to suggest a solution. I will need to keep the `SingleChildScroll` for smaller sized phones. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my question, the reason why I use `SingleChildScroll` is to make it not overflow for smaller sized phones. However, for larger phones, the container is not taking the full width of the available space.

So I solved this by checking if the screen height is below certain value.
If the screen height is less than 534.0 (a height that I picked), then use the `SingleChildScroll` widget or `ListView`.
If it is larger then, use `Expanded` for the container that needs to take the height available.

Hope this helps anyone!